# php multiply int values seperated by comma and dot

Tags: php, math, int

In my current application a user can have a "prepaid" amount of money on his account. The value is stored in cents. Now in case of a user tries to transfer money from one account to another he should be able to use values like: "1,53", "1.53" and "1". Now I need to check if the entered amount is below the amount he's able to transfer.

```
 if (($request->amount * 100) <= $user->calculateAmount())
```

The function $user->calculateAmount() returns values like for example "351" which stands for 3,51€ (saved in cents).
I know the problem is the ",", using a "." works fine, but user should be able to use both. Is there a better way or did I need to use str_replace()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:
http://codepad.org/NW4e9hQH

Currently there are no other method to parse this to float.

Comment: Nope, I thought so, but then I've tested it and it is cutting behind the `,`. The same like `(float) $var`.

Comment: Hmm the function you posted is a bit overloaded for me. Users can just enter values like (1.53|1,52|1) not the value itself but only in this style. RegEx will check. Do you have a function with not soo much overload but short style? Using str_replace() will make it sooo long...

Comment: Then why not simply `str_replace(',', '.', $var);` This will search for `,` in $var and replace this with a `.`.

Comment: It works with Italian notation. After doing calculation you can restore the comma decimal separator by calling `number_format($result, 5, ',', '')`